# WPF - is checking System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached frequently considered a good security check (in release mode)?

Tags: wpf, security, debugging

I want to enhance the security of a WPF application, and one of the risks in production environment is that crackers can attach the application process to a debugger (either Visual studio or other debuggers that exist out there) and have some insights (I am not sure if it is true, but I think it might be possible to flip a condition when a license dialog is shown and thus passing the license check and use the application normally), anyway, Is a simple snippet like this

```cs
var myTimer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
};
myTimer.Tick += (_, _) =>
{
    if(Debugger.IsAttached)
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
};
myTimer.Start();
```

considered enough to prevent the debugger-attack?

Answer (score 1):

In short, that is a developer aid, and not a security measure. It is extremely easy to defeat, and many tools out there can bypass it.

You will want to look into using a .net "Protector" or "Packer", which will help to obfuscate the shipping binary. Just keep in mind that none of them are 100% infallible.